How to sort folders by a specific subfolder's size?
I need a command line utility (preferably for Windows 10 but Linux (Debian) is fine too) to sort folders based on a subdirectory size. For example I have multiple mods for a Steam game, and each mod has its own \sounds subdirectory (some mods may NOT have this subfolder, so it should count them as zero-size), so I want to sort mods based on \sounds size.
The folder structure looks like this:
SteamWorkshop/GameID
  mod1
    sounds
        folder1
          file1.wav
          file2.wav
        folder2
          file3.wav
          file4.wav
    scripts
      etc
  mod2
    sounds
        file5_nosubfolder.wav
    scripts
      etc
  mod3
    scripts
      etc

Note that some of the sounds folder may have subdirectories, some may only have files in them, or no file at all, or a mod may have no sounds folder at all. So I need to calculate the total size of all files and subfolders recursively, and list all the mods based on size of sounds, something like this:
mod1 sounds: 1.234MB
mod2 sounds: 0.123MB
mod3 sounds: 0MB

I don't even know which command does this. grep / findstr? ls?
Any help is appreciated!

Do you need to do this recursively? Like a tree view and in each directory (no matter the depth) the subdirectories are sorted according to the rule you gave. Or do you need just direct subdirectories of some directory to be sorted, without descending deeper? The description and the example directory structure suggest the latter with the caveat that sounds may be arbitrarily deep(!). Please [edit] and clearly state this.

@KamilMaciorowski Sorry for the late response. Yes, it's only one folder with direct children that I want to sort. Other than sounds/file vs sounds/folder/file, all other depths are constant. Also I just realize I added an "assets" folder in my example, that's wrong. /sounds is always a direct child of the mod folder.

This is an example that uses tools available in Ubuntu, but the idea is general and can be implemented with other tools. Even in Ubuntu you may want to adjust the solution to your needs.

Place yourself in the parent directory of the directory you want to analyze. In your case the directory you want to analyze is GameID and the parent directory is SteamWorkshop.

Make a copy of the whole directory you want to analyze. Use hardlinks or reflinks (if possible).
cp -rlx --no-preserve=all GameID GameID_copy


In the copy remove everything you don't want to count:
find GameID_copy ! -type d ! -path '*/sounds/*' -delete

The above command deliberately leaves all directories intact, so in the next step you will be able to see the whole directory structure.

Analyze what is left:
ncdu GameID_copy


Remove the copy when done:
rm -r GameID_copy




Thank you! I edited my example to reflect that /sounds (if exists) is always a direct child of /mod_n. It may have children folders or files, though. And I would like a way without copying the whole directory, it's quite big. But I will look into ncdu, thanks!

@wololoo "And I would like a way without copying" -- This is what hardlinks give you.

Oh got it, thank you! Why don't we work on the original directory? Is it a precaution in case I accidentally delete stuff?

@wololoo The step number 3 deletes stuff to "exclude" it.
